# Is there any way to install Metro/Modern UI applications without using the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get a Windows 8 side-loading product key?](https://superuser.com/questions/492800/where-can-i-get-a-windows-8-side-loading-product-key)

Is there any way to install Metro/Modern UI applications without using the Windows Store?
I heard that the Windows Store would be the only way to get applications. Is this true, or can they be manually installed?